# Show icon to the right of a Headless UI Popover.Button

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using the Headless Ui Popover.Button and I am not displaying any default text so I want the Chevron to show to the right. it does this when I have an item selected but not when nothing is in the box.

```
<Popover.Button className="flex justify-between w-60 text-sm font-bold uppercase items-center h-14 px-4 border-t border-b border-black rounded-none">
        {
          types.map((type) => (type.isSelected ? type.name : ''))
        }
        
        {open ? (
          <ChevronUpIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-black" />
        ) : (
           
          <ChevronDownIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-black" />
          
        )}
      </Popover.Button>
```

if i change the justify-between to justify-end it moves it but then the selected text is moved to the right as well.

any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I would say, have `justify-end` as default. When an item is selected, replace the class with `justify-between`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the first part in another `div`.

```html
<div>
    {
        types.map((type) => (type.isSelected ? type.name : ''))
    }
</div>
```

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input");
var buttonText = document.querySelector("#buttonText");
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Item 1"
  } else {
    buttonText.innerHTML = ""
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com//tailwindcss@2.1.1/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="flex justify-between w-60 text-sm font-bold uppercase items-center h-14 px-4 border-t border-b border-black rounded-none">
  <div id="buttonText">
  </div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M19 9l-7 7-7-7" />
  </svg>
</button>

<input type="checkbox" class="mt-4">Item 1</input>
```

Comment: The div tag did work. had to also add flex w-full justify-end for the classname.